# Good free tool for editing and merging XML

Tags: xml

I need free tool for editing and merging 2 XML documents. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open Source XML Diff written in Java](http://www.roseindia.net/opensource/xmldiff.php)

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). It has an ability to compare XML documents (just enable DisplayXMLFiles).